# kdb matrix functions improvement

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication, kdb, dolphindb, matrix-inverse

Did anyone come across using kdb’s matrix function? I found it quite slow compared to other tools.

For inverse matrix function `inv` on a 1000 by 1000 float matrix , It took kdb+ 166,682 milliseconds for 10 executions.  For matrix multiplication,  it took 3,380 milliseconds, where the two matrices share the same dimension as 1000 by 1000.

I also tried the same experiment on  DolphinDB, a similar time series database with built-in analytics features ([DolphinDB](https://www.dolphindb.com/downloads.html) ).  DolphinDB’s `inv` function is about 17 times faster and matrix multiplication is about 6 times faster.

I would think matrix operation optimization should be something well established. Can any kdb expert explain the reason behind it or if there are any ways to improve it?

I used KDB+ 4.0 64 bit version and DolphinDB_Linux_V2.00.7(DolphinDB community version: 2 cores and 8GB memory). Both experiments are conducted using 2 cores of CPU.

**KDB implementation**

```
// Start the server
rlwrap -r taskset -c 0,1 ./l64/q -p 5002 -s 2

// The code
ma:1000 cut (-5.0+ 1000000?10.0)
mb:1000 cut (-5.0+ 1000000?10.0)

\t do[10;inv ma]
16682

\t do[10;ma mmu mb]
3380
```

**DolphinDB implementation**

```
// Start the server
rlwrap -r ./dolphindb -localSite localhost:5002:local5002 -localExecutors 1

// The code
ma=(-5.0+ rand(10.0,1000000))$1000:1000;
mb=(-5.0+ rand(10.0,1000000))$1000:1000;
timer(10) ma.inv();
Time elapsed: 975.349 ms

timer(10) ma**mb;
Time elapsed: 581.618 ms
```

Answer (score 3):

DolphinDB uses `openblas` for matrix operations like `inv` while kdb+ doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody here is privy to what kdb and dolphin are doing under the covers for these operations, other than knowing that `inv` in kdb uses LU decomposition (previously it used Cholesky decomposition as well).

In general kdb is not optimised for matrix operations, it is optimised for vector operations. Case in point - if you have enough worker threads and use `peach`:

```
q)\t do[10;ma mmu mb]
2182
q)\t do[10;mmu[;mb]peach ma]
375
```

If you wanted to do serious matrix operations in kdb you would load C libraries to carry out the heavy lifting. For example using the Q math library (http://althenia.net/qml):

```
q)\t inv ma
1588
q)\t .qml.minv ma
689
```